# How to use Platformview to view Applovin_max MREC and banner ads

Tags: flutter, ads, banner, applovin, platformview

Is there anyone here who has used platformview to view applovin_max MREC and banner ads in flutter?

I was trying to make Android and Native views then implement it on Dart side by creating a MRECWidget for example then use it somewhere in my code.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, or **other off-site resources** (e.g., "some samples from Github or study materials") are off-topic. You'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your guidance regarding asking for off-site resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be glad to help you with integrating AppLovin MAX MREC and banner ads in Flutter, but using platform views for this purpose isn't the recommended approach.

you can use `applovin_max` package.

Here's how to use AppLovinMAX.preloadAd(adUnitId) to pre-load an ad for a specific unit ID in your Flutter app:

```
String adUnitId = "YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID"; // Replace with your actual ID

void preLoadAd() async {
  await AppLovinMAX.preloadAd(adUnitId);
  print("Ad pre-loaded for unit ID: $adUnitId");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Currently Im using applovin_max but it seems that the loading of ads takes time so i was thinking of viewing it via platformView instead.

Comment: Use AppLovinMAX.preloadAd(adUnitId) to pre-load an ad for a specific unit ID.

Comment: Thank you for that! I tried using loadAd() even inside init but the ads seems to rebuild everytime I show the widget. While programmatic MRec works great, its position is on the whole device screen but doesnt work inside a widget I intended to show MRec.